# Custom sorting using Dgrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am using Dgrid and I am aware of the sorting parameter which can sort asc and desc but I want to sort via a custom order which I guess needs to be done via the store. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all of those wanting to this, there is an outstanding issue I have opened on github.
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/276

Essentially as of answering, there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: Very interesting. All im trying to do is get sort without case-sensitivity but it's almost impossible to find in this code! Any other words of wisdom since your foray?